# IIS - ADFS Token Signing

Tags: iis, certificate, token, adfs

Our ADFS will replace its ADFS Token signature, I'm sitting with a lot of IIS server 2012 r2
If the sites have an setting to use the old certificate, I have to configure to use the new certificate.
However, I do not find this setting, any of you who know?

Comment: IIS does not have a setting for ADFS token. It your sites use that, review the site source code with the developers please. Too broad to ask here, as no one here can see the code.

Comment: i shall check with them, thank you for your respond

Answer (score 0):

IIS does not use the ADFS token signing certificate.

Only ADFS and other CP / RP need it.

Just to note that if you want to update the ADFS SSL certificate, this does need to be changed for https sites in IIS.